# How can I merge a new object to existing object in an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeerror

[image]

I have array like above. I want to input `{"temperature":{"work":30,"home":24}}` object to the first of array.

So array should start with:

```
0 : {title : "tptp", {"temperature":{"work":30,"home":24}}, lastview:"12-12 21:2"}
```

My code is

```
console.log("below is home");
console.log(this.home);
console.log(this.home[0].push({"temperature": {"work":30,"home":24}}));
```

But I have error `TypeError: this.home[0].push is not a function`.

Comment: `home[0]` is an object - do you want to merge the objects?

Comment: My bad. I did not see that you actually wanted to *merge* the objects.

Comment: this.home[0] probably isn't an array

Answer (score 0):

The expected output you posted isn't possible, i.e.

```
{title : "tptp", {"temperature":{"work":30,"home":24}}, lastview:"12-12 21:2"}
```

what you probably want is

```
{title : "tptp", "temperature":{"work":30,"home":24}, lastview:"12-12 21:2"}
```

which you can achieve with

```
Object.assign(this.home[0], {"temperature": {"work":30,"home":24}})
```

Answer (score 0):

`push` function works with `Array`, not with `Object` and

```
{title : "tptp", {"temperature":{"work":30,"home":24}}, lastview:"12-12 21:2"} // Ivalid Json
```

You have to interduce new key `temperature` according to your requirement.

```
console.log("below is home");
console.log(this.home);
this.home[0]["temperature"] = {"work":30,"home":24};
console.log( this.home[0] );
```

Output will be

```
[
  {
    "title": "tptp",
    "lastview": "12-12 21:2",
    "temperature": {
      "work": 30,
      "home": 24
    }
  },
  {
    "title": "gngn",
    "lastview": "12-12 19:29"
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is ,

```
this.home[0].put("temperature": {"work":30,"home":24});
```